# Get model by table name in yii2

Tags: yii2, yii2-model

I have one method in several models, implemented in different ways.
I only know the name of table in database. I must find model of this table. 
How to do?

```
interface BaseIndexedModel
{
    public function writeSometext();
}
```

and some models implement it. Example

```
class First extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord implements BaseIndexedModel
{
    public function writeSometext(){
       return "1";
    }
}

class Second extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord implements BaseIndexedModel
{
    public function writeSometext(){
       return "2";
    }
}
```

Next on a certain event I need to call the desired model and this method. But when I call, I will only know the database table, but not the model.

If table "first", `First::writeSometext();`
If table "second", `Second:: writeSometext();`

Comment: if you made model correctly then name is always firstletter capital of tablename

Comment: Hi! Yes, I know it, but I was still looking for another option.

Comment: ok but explain the scenerio more why and how you want to use it.

Comment: I edited the question.

Comment: i think either you have a list of models somewhere,  or the method i told you, because you only know table name from db, so best would be same name as table and model. which is more dynamic

Comment: Why not crate array which maps AR classes to related tables?

Comment: @rob006 because it will be difficult to maintain, constantly append new tables

Comment: @AhmedSunny I will create a function to which I will transfer the name of the table and from it generate the name of the model. I will process the first letter of the capital and _ simbol in table name... 'tirst' (table) - First (model), 'second_table' - SecondTable (model) etc...

Comment: yes that what i wwould do

Comment: ucfirst() use this. if you need help with function, you can add details to question regarding table names

Comment: Tnx, I think I can do it

Comment: @AhmedSunny If you want you can make your comment to answer so I would be able to accept it. Thank you for advices!

Comment: @Mary It should be more flexible and less magic than generating model FQN based on table name (you need to follow strict conventions if you want to support that, which is not always that simple). Adding new entry to models map should not be a big deal when you compare this to creating model class (and probably CRUD) and could be partially automated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it this way when you get the table name

```
public function getModelName($table_name) {
    $table_name = 'first_table';  
    // $table_name = 'first';// if name is single word then comment the next line
    $table_split = explode("_",$table_name);
    $model = ucfirst($table_split[0]).ucfirst($table_split[1]);
    return $model;
}
```

you can call this function 
and check if it exists

```
$model = getModelName($table_name);
var_dump($model);
```

Comment: yes, but model name is without prefix in Yii, and also he is getting table name, and you can customize this according to your need, you can add an extra step, removing prefix from table name and do the rest

Comment: Models does not have prefixes, but table names does. This is how Gii generates model name, and it is still not perfect: https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-gii/blob/60c53d399ebf12cac9b8daa1fa9d81b8b1ee9a91/src/generators/model/Generator.php#L870-L912

Comment: i know, for this question this is fine, but not for all. as i am using different schemas and i cant use crud, yii cant handle it.

Answer (score 0):

This one allows you to have 1+ words in the table name. In contrast to the solution posted by Ahmed Sunny, which only works for 2 words.

```
public function getModelName($tableName) {
    $tableSplit = explode("_",$ruleTableName);
    $className = '';

    foreach ($tableSplit as $word){
        $className .= ucfirst($word);
    }

    return $className;
}
```